# Difference between Created and Created. in SharePoint REST API Call

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I call SPO Rest API and in response I found two type of dates. I am not able to find any documentation on their difference especially the one with Dot (.)
[Both Dates are shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03m9b.png)
We want to use one with Dot as its in standard format, but not sure about its authenticity. We are using RenderListDataAsStream as end point to get data.

Any documentation of properties coming with Dot(.) will be helpful to understand it. In attached image count is also another same example having dot.

[P.S: here are the differnt ways to access them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odfdn.png)

Comment: I never saw this field. Is it possible that someone created a field named `Created.` ? That said, which API are you calling ?

Comment: Well, the dot is also coming with Modified. and FirstPublishedDate. so it is not possible and moreover its also coming in count. 

We are using spHttpClient.post with /_api/web/Lists/Getbytitle('Site Pages')/RenderListDataAsStream

Both of them are accessible using different way too. One is with like result.Created and other one is like result["Created."]

Comment: Maybe it's related to the very specific `RenderListDataAsStream` method. What are you trying to achieve? why don't simply get items from .../yourList/items ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the value of the normal named key (like technical field name) represents the value shown in UI to a user. So it is affected by the regional settings of the web.

The value of the additional "."-key (technical field name plus ".") represents the UTC-0 value in ISO format (like the data is stored in DB internaly).

For example:

```
"Created": "0;#2022-09-07 06:17:37",  // timestamp by Regional Settings
"Created.": "2022-09-07T13:17:37Z",  // UTC-0 in ISO format
```